# round up to 5 decimal places in java?

Tags: java

I have a Sting value contains in Exponential

```
class round{    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String a ="2.4545776339999877E7";
        double roundOff = Math.round(a);
        System.out.println(roundOff);
    }
}
```

So i want to round off upto 5 decimal vaue. How to do it please?

Comment: Please use Code-Tags to improve readability.

Comment: you too lazy to format, me too lazy to answer

Comment: To you mean 5 digits of precision, 5 digits after the decimal point, or to the nearest 1/100000th as these are all different things. Can you say what the expected result is?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to output (or get some `String`) out of this float value you may do this:

```
double val = Double.valueOf(a);
String str = String.format("%.5f", val);
System.out.println (str);
```

Else if you really want to get double with 5 signs of precision after integer part, you may write the following:

```
double val = ... // the same as in the previous example
double val5Signs = Math.floor(val * 1e5) / 1e5;
```

Comment: This will round to the nearest 1/100000th.

Comment: @PeterLawrey it's what OP requesting, isn't it?

Comment: +1 It might be or the OP might expect `2.45458E7` which is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Java Decimal-Formatter for Output-Purposes:

```
double input = Double.valueOf(a);
DecimalFormatSymbols symbol = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
symbol.setDecimalSeparator('.');
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#0.00000", symbol).format(input));
```